# Wait for the browser to do a refresh

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I'm automating tests using protractor.
In the web app that I'm automating, there's a button that, when pressed, refreshes the page.

Is there a way to wait for a refresh to happen & complete using protractor ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use for tests GET variables?

So basically on first load you click the button and it appends "?is_reloaded=true".

Maybe this could help.

But I badly have no experience in protractor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing the functionality of the refresh button? If not then just check for changes in the page that you have refreshed, if yes try injecting a flag in the page (window) by using `browser.executeScript()`

For example:

```
let getCurrentWindowHash = () => { 
   return browser.executeScript("return window.location.hash");
};

await browser.executeScript("window.location.hash = 'Not yet refreshed'");

// Confirm that the has has been set
console.log(`current window hash = ${getCurrentWindowHash()}`); // Should log '#Not yet refreshed'

// click the refresh button

// On refresh, window properties would get reset. 
// If the window location hash is empty, then your page was refreshed.
console.log(`current window hash = ${getCurrentWindowHash()}`); // Should be empty
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not working
const h = await this.browser.executeScript("return window.location.hash");
await console.log(`HASSHOU ${h}`);
await this.browser.executeScript("window.location.hash = 'Not yet refreshed'");
const h2 = await this.browser.executeScript("return window.location.hash");await console.log(`HASSHOU2 ${h2}`);

And this logs:

HASSHOU #/Login?langfr
HASSHOU2 #/Login

It's not changing the hash to not yet refreshed